# Is there a way to filter a row in R based on a categorical column and a date column

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, plyr

I have a data set in R that looks something link this:

| ClientID | Category | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Person1 | CategoryA | 2020-09-01 |
| Person1 | CategoryA | 2020-09-30 |
| Person2 | CategoryA | 2020-07-25 |
| Person2 | CategoryA | 2020-08-31 |
| Person1 | CategoryB | 2020-03-15 |
| Person1 | CategoryB | 2020-09-14 |
| Person2 | CategoryB | 2020-06-17 |
| Person2 | CategoryB | 2020-10-10 |

What I would like to do is filter it to only return the row of the most recent date in each category for every client, so it would look like this:

| ClientID | Category | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Person1 | CategoryA | 2020-09-30 |
| Person1 | CategoryB | 2020-09-14 |
| Person2 | CategoryA | 2020-08-31 |
| Person2 | CategoryB | 2020-10-10 |

I have tried

```
library(plyr)

dataSet %>% filter(Category == "CategoryA",Date == max(Date))
```

I knew this wouldn't work the moment I typed it, but I am lost on where to go. I have considered subsetting the data on the different categories (there are only 4), but then I am still lost with filtering by max date per client (because at least then, I could `rbind()` the results of each subset into a final data table). But alas, I am stuck.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can try

```
df %>%
  group_by(ClientID, Category) %>%
  filter(Date == max(Date))
```

which gives

```
  ClientID Category  Date
  <chr>    <chr>     <date>
1 Person1  CategoryA 2020-09-30
2 Person2  CategoryA 2020-08-31
3 Person1  CategoryB 2020-09-14
4 Person2  CategoryB 2020-10-10
```

---

A base R option using `subset` + `ave`

```
subset(
  df,
  Date == ave(Date, ClientID, Category, FUN = max)
)
```

gives

```
  ClientID  Category       Date
2  Person1 CategoryA 2020-09-30
4  Person2 CategoryA 2020-08-31
6  Person1 CategoryB 2020-09-14
8  Person2 CategoryB 2020-10-10
```

---

A `data.table` option

```
> setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, max), by = .(ClientID, Category)]
   ClientID  Category       Date
1:  Person1 CategoryA 2020-09-30
2:  Person2 CategoryA 2020-08-31
3:  Person1 CategoryB 2020-09-14
4:  Person2 CategoryB 2020-10-10
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(ClientID = c("Person1", "Person1", "Person2", 
"Person2", "Person1", "Person1", "Person2", "Person2"), Category = c("CategoryA",
"CategoryA", "CategoryA", "CategoryA", "CategoryB", "CategoryB",
"CategoryB", "CategoryB"), Date = structure(c(18506, 18535, 18468,
18505, 18336, 18519, 18430, 18545), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA,
-8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
library(dplyr)

dataSet %>% 
   group_by(Client_ID, Category) %>% 
   mutate(max_date=max(Date)) %>% 
   filter(Date==max_date)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is use of `dplyr::slice`. Thanks [user ThomasIsCoding for the sample data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65500644/7941188).

I don't say it's better than the filter option, but it's just another way. One could also make this shorter by using which.max(Date) within slice, instead of arranging first.

```r
library(dplyr)

foodf <- structure(list(ClientID = c("Person1", "Person1", "Person2", 
                            "Person2", "Person1", "Person1", "Person2", "Person2"), Category = c("CategoryA",
                                                                                                 "CategoryA", "CategoryA", "CategoryA", "CategoryB", "CategoryB",
                                                                                                 "CategoryB", "CategoryB"), Date = structure(c(18506, 18535, 18468,
                                                                                                                                               18505, 18336, 18519, 18430, 18545), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA,
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   -8L), class = "data.frame")
foodf %>% 
  arrange(ClientID, Category, Date) %>%
  group_by(ClientID, Category) %>%
  slice(n())
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#> # Groups:   ClientID, Category [4]
#>   ClientID Category  Date      
#>   <chr>    <chr>     <date>    
#> 1 Person1  CategoryA 2020-09-30
#> 2 Person1  CategoryB 2020-09-14
#> 3 Person2  CategoryA 2020-08-31
#> 4 Person2  CategoryB 2020-10-10
```